# How to select distinct number by his state

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have table like this :

```
create table test(num integer,state text,col1 integer);
```

and sample data :

```
insert into test(num,state,col1) values(1234,'done',1),(1234,'done',2),(1234,'done',11),
(23123,'done',1),(23123,'notdone',1),(23123,'any_other_states',2131);
```

want select distinct num from this table where state is only done, for example output must be : 1234
I try something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT num
FROM test
WHERE state = 'done' and state not in('notdone','any_other_states')
GROUP BY num;
```

But output is 1234 and 23123. How to do it ?

Comment: First thing you need to do is decide which DBMS you are actually using and tag appropriately.

Comment: Regardless of the actual DBMS you are only ever going to get those values because you can only get those where state = 'done'. As such, the not in portion is redundant.

Comment: @SeanLange I added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgresql:

```
select num
from test
group by num
having bool_and(state = 'done')
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE

Comment: thank you it works for me,i will accept answer in 8 minutes

Answer (score 1):

you should exclude the num where in notdone  ,and any_othe_status

```
  SELECT DISTINCT num
  FROM test
  WHERE state = 'done' and num not in 
  ( 
    select num 
    from test 
    where state in ('notdone','any_other_states')

  )
```